# Element not selected as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I'm trying to select an element with JavaScript using the following snippet of code inside an AngularJS application.

```
var assicurazione = document.getElementsByClassName("assicurazione");
var aLength = assicurazione.length;

for(var key in assicurazione){
   console.log("key: ", key);
   console.log("assicurazione[key] ", assicurazione[key]);
}

console.log("assicurazione element: ", assicurazione);
console.log("assicurazione.length: ", aLength);

for(var a = 0; a < aLength; a++){
   console.log("Element: ", assicurazione[a]); // not firing
   console.log("a value: ", a); // not firing
}
```

The output of the console.log is the following:

[image]

The loop is not working as expected because the length is 0, but the element has a length property and in this case it is set to 16 so I have no idea why it wouldn't loop through the element.

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: The loop is working, what is your problem?

Comment: the assicurazione element is not behaving as expected.

Comment: 'as expected' means what? What is your expectation of how it should work?

Comment: It's working fine as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/zt1cpa9q/ what is your problem?

Comment: uploading more pics and code

Comment: uploaded a more describing version

Comment: Added an answer, glad  to help you.

Comment: Is it possible this is a timing issue? In your first loop the value of the length key is zero. But when you console print the element it shows the length property is 16.

Comment: Remember that console.log is async. So what you see as output may not match exactly the order of what is happening in your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: I've tried with the proposed solutions from you guys but it seems the code is not behaving as expected. I haven't modified the native objects in any ways, nor the native methods that come with them. I'll try something new tomorrow. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @mnemosdev As you can see in the working fiddle examples, it works like a charm. What is your problem so?

Comment: well, the problem might be caused by something that is external to the normal javascript behaviour.. I'll investigate further and i'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code in the context of this page -- but changing the classname --  it works for me as expected. I suspect something else is likely going on with your code. Have you tried `angular.element`?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

```
var assicurazione = document.getElementsByClassName("module");
var aLength = assicurazione.length;

console.log(assicurazione, aLength);

for(var a = 0; a < aLength; a++){
   console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried wrapping the element with angular.element, no luck tho'

Comment: Is there something else in your code changing some native prototypes? I wonder if your `Array.prototype` or `NodeList.prototype` may have been altered by some other code? Because as other's have said, the code you show works fine. This almost certainly points to something else being the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to access each element, your loop would need to look more like this, ignoring the changes I've made to variable names.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("mine");
var aLength = elements.length;

console.log(aLength);
console.log(elements);

for(var a = 0; a < aLength; a++){
   console.log(elements[a]);
}
```

Check out the [working example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efo0pmcd/).

Comment: Except it does work. HTMLCollection is an array-like collection. Try the jsfiddle, or refer to the MDN docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection